# Screen time: restrict web content on iOS only

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, screen-time

I'd like to enable the "Limit Adult Websites" Screen Time option on iOS / iPadOS devices *only*.

Every time the **Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Content Restrictions > Web Content** is enabled on an iOS device, the laptop / desktop computers on the related iCloud account mirrors the setting as well.

I already have filtering software on real computers and the corresponding webproxyfilterd dramatically slows network connection speed (I get about 1/50th the throughput).

Using iOS 14.2 / macOS Catalina

Comment: You could turn off screen time share via iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the nudge from @X_841 I ended up turning off screen time altogether for my macOS device in **System Preferences > Screen Time**